# DateTimePicker not display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use Bootstrap DateTimePicker in my web application.
I used [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) tutorial but it does not work for me.

This is my code (all libraries are imported)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.*js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

thank you

Comment: What is dollar? Why not run code on document ready?     `$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });` I see you included jquery, so this should work.

Comment: I mean $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

Comment: Press F12 on chrome when running. Do you see any errors?

Comment: I found the problem thanks to you.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.*js"> was not found so i replace it by <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: How to do to validate your answer??